# Mapping collections using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm trying to map an array into an `ICollection` of type `<T>.`

Basically I want to be able to do:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<X[], Y>();
```

Where `Y` is `Collection<T>`

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the behavior you're seeing right now?

Comment: Just unable to map between an array to an ICollection<T>. Mapping exception is thrown.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You don't need to setup your mapping for collections, just the element types.
So just:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<X, Y>();
Mapper.Map<X[], Collection<Y>>(objectToMap);
```

See here for more info: http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Lists%20and%20Arrays&referringTitle=Home

Comment: What about if I want to map a string[] to a Y? e.g. where each string in the array will map to a different property of Y?

Comment: Link to automaper is broken

Answer (score 3):

Now it looks like you can use:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<X,Y>(); 
var listOfX = Mapper.Map<List<X>>(someIEnumerableOfY);
```