# Automapper: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping

Tags: c#, automapper

I have the following code:

```
var data = repo.GetAll();
Mapper.CreateMap<Products_GetAll_Result, Product>();
return Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Products_GetAll_Result>, List<FurnitureStore.Models.Product>>(data.ToList());
```

I get the following message in the exception:

```
{"Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
Products_GetAll_Result -> Product
FurnitureStore.DataLayer.Products_GetAll_Result -> FurnitureStore.Models.Product

Destination path:
List`1[0]

Source value:
FurnitureStore.DataLayer.Products_GetAll_Result"}
```

I tried anything I could think of but I can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You sure that `Product` and `FurnitureStore.Models.Product` are same class?

Comment: Also you don't need to call `CreateMap` before every `Map`, just do it once. Or even use `DynamicMap` without prior map creation if mapping between your types is trivial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT**

When you create your mapping

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Products_GetAll_Result, Product>();
```

Why are you not using `FurnitureStore.Models.Product` ? As when you are mapping you are using `FurnitureStore.Models.Product` rather than just `Product` class. (Assuming both classes are different)

**EDIT**

Removed the code which was redundant as OP's mapping style was correct

Comment: nope.  
{"Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.\r\n\r\nMapping types:\r\nProducts_GetAll_Result -> Product\r\nFurnitureStore.DataLayer.Products_GetAll_Result -> FurnitureStore.Models.Product\r\n\r\nDestination path:\r\nProduct\r\n\r\nSource value:\r\nFurnitureStore.DataLayer.Products_GetAll_Result"}

Comment: See edited answer, I noticed something in your code.

Comment: excellent, it works now. Not sure how I missed that. Indeed they are two different classes. Now it works with the code I posted in the question, from IEnumerable to List directly,without the select.

Comment: Yeah, even I missed that when answering your question :)

Comment: @Sneh, although you can map individual items you don't have too. `AutoMapper` will handle collections [just fine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1718703/2594597), if you create map for individual items.

Comment: Thanks @LeonidVasilyev, I will remember that and will use it next time.

Answer (score 2):

You could use that:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Products_GetAll_Result, Product>().ReverseMap();
```