# How to map two list with automapper?

Tags: c#, automapper

I have two classes in the different location.

```
namespace IVR.MyEndpointApi.POCO
{
    [Table("MyServiceUrl")]
    public class MyURL
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("FacilityID")]
        public int FacilityId { get; set; }
        [Column("Url")]
        public string Url { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace OpsTools.Models
{
    public class MyServiceEndpoint
    {
        public int FacilityId { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In another method, I get the list and want to convert then return it as the desired type. I manually do it as below:

```
public List<MyServiceEndpoint> GetAllUrls()
{
    var management = GetMyEndpointManagement();
    var list = management.GetAllUrls(); 
    var urlList = new List<MyServiceEndpoint>();
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        // the type of item is MyURL
        var MyUrl = new MyServiceEndpoint();
        myUrl.FacilityId = item.FacilityId;
        myUrl.Url = item.Url;
        urlList.Add(myUrl);
    }
    return urlList;
}
```

My question: can I apply AutoMapper to it?

**EDIT:**

I used the code:

```
        var myUrls = management.GetAllUrls();
        var urlList = new List<MyServiceEndpoint>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<MyServiceEndpoint, MyURL>();
        urlList = Mapper.Map<List<MyServiceEndpoint>, List<MyURL>>(myUrls);
        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

However, it has the error:

```
Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to ....
```

Comment: you mean `Mapper.Map<List<MyURL>, List<MyServiceEndpoint>>(list);`?

Comment: @CodeCaster, I am not sure if the attribute`[key]` affect it?

Comment: @Ric, I edited the question. It seems the attribute disallows it. Anyway to ignore it?

Comment: Possible duplicate (based on your last edit) [Mapping collections using AutoMapper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623993/mapping-collections-using-automapper). Also attributes play no part in your exception.

Comment: you need to map both ways, not just one way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you inspect the actual exception (you left the relevant part off), you'll see that `Mapper.Map<TSource, TDestination>()` tries to map from and to the wrong types.

The full error will read:

> cannot convert from `System.Collections.Generic.List<MyURL>` to `System.Collections.Generic.List<MyServiceEndpoint>`

Which means that call will actually try to map *from* `List<MyServiceEndpoint>`, requiring an argument of that type, which your source list isn't.

Simply switch the types in the `Map()` call:

```
urlList = Mapper.Map<List<MyURL>, List<MyServiceEndpoint>>(myUrls);
```

Or remove the new list creation entirely, move the declaration and use type inference:

```
var urlList = Mapper.Map<List<MyServiceEndpoint>>(myUrls);
```

Answer (score 1):

Oops, come on. I change the order, then it works.

From

```
 urlList = Mapper.Map<List<MyServiceEndpoint>, List<MyURL>>(myUrls);
```

To

```
 urlList = Mapper.Map<List< List<MyURL>,MyServiceEndpoint>>(myUrls);
```