# Convert an array of one datatype to array of another in NET core in an efficient way?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, .net-core

I have an array of database entities that I need to convert to some different class in order to serve as a REST request result:

```
DatabaseDTO[] arrayFromDb = _repo.GetAllData();
OutgoinDTO[] = convertFromDatabaseDTO (arrayFromDb);
```

what is the most efficient way to do so (I assume that `OutgoingDTO` has a constructor that takes DatabaseDTO)

Comment: Given that you are converting between arrays, maybe [`Array.ConvertAll()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.convertall?view=netframework-4.8) will do the trick? This is likely to be optimally efficient.

Comment: define "efficient"; coding effort? memory usage? runtime? dependency tree? lines of code? allocations? These are all competing factors: you can't say "all of them"

Comment: Why not create a new array with the desired size and just loop? That's what [Array.ConvertAll](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,1031) does. Do you have a specific performance issue? The conversion constructor itself is extra complexity that binds the two types together for example. Why not use a separate conversion method? Or AutoMapper? What are you looking for?

Comment: One approach is to not build the array of the "wrong" types to begin with. If you could convert them on the fly, you'd save a whole bunch of memory. See if your repository might not be amenable to a rewrite where it returns `IEnumerable` instead of an array.

Comment: Explicitly, `DatabaseDTO[] arrayFromDb = _repo.GetAllData();
OutgoinDTO[] = Array.ConvertAll(arrayFromDb, x => new OutgoinDTO(x));`

Comment: @JeroenMostert _to not build the array of the "wrong" types to begin with_ - this rarely happens in practice. You usually have data on the DB side and you need it for various cases but you only want to show part of that data to each API

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't require returning that data *as an array*. Even `List<>` would usually be more efficient memory-wise (as it doesn't require allocating a new array of the "right" size when you're done reading), and `IEnumerable` allows the consumer to decide what collection they'd like to put the result in -- if indeed they need a collection to begin with. That's the difference between having a big array of `DatabaseDTO` which the needs to be converted once more, and having only a single `DatabaseDTO` at any given time which is transformed into an `OutgoingDTO` as the data is being read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use **LINQ** to map an object from another, as:

```
var outgoinDTO = arrayFromDb.Select(x => new OutgoinDTO() {
  outgoing_param1 = arrayFromDb.param1,
  outgoing_param2 = arrayFromDb.param2,
  outgoing_param3 = calcSum(arrayFromDb.param2, arrayFromDb.param3),
  ..
  outgoing_paramn = arrayFromDb.paramn
});

calcSum(int a, int b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

So, you can calculate some results for Dto parameters from your DbClass.
If both classes have same parameters (DbClass and DtoClass), you can use AutoMapper, how @Adem Aygun said below

Answer (score 1):

you can use [AutoMapper.Collection](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection)

```
Mapper.Map<List<OrderDTO>,List<Order>>(orderDtos, orders);
```

and here [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1718703/4458106)

for different [members](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14778305/4458106):

```
    Mapper.CreateMap<Employee, EmployeeDto>()
   .ForMember(dest => dest.FullName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name));
```

Comment: use automapper only if almost parameters exist in both classes. if need to execute some functions to calculate params result, will be better to use linq