# Problem with mapping objects with automapper

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, automapper, dto

I have a problem with mapping. Here is my **model**.

```
    public class Post
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
    }
```

**My Dto:**

```
public class PostForReturnDto
    {
        public PostForReturnDto()
        {
             Created = DateTime.Now;
        }
         public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
    }
```

**AutoMapperProfiles.cs**

```
 CreateMap<Post, PostForReturnDto>()
            .ForMember(p => p.Author,
             opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.User.KnownAs));
```

**RepositoryContext**

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<Post>> GetPosts() {
             var posts = _context.Posts
            .Include(u => u.User)
            .OrderByDescending(p => p.Created)
            .ToListAsync();

            return await posts;
        }
```

While in debug mode in the PostController I receive the following information with the user object inside.

[image]
[image]

I'm trying to map KnownAs property from the User object to my DTO, but with no success.
The error is:

AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
Mapping types:
List`1 -> PostForReturnDto
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[DateApp.API.Models.Post, DateApp.API, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] -> DateApp.API.Dtos.PostForReturnDto
   at lambda_method(Closure , List`1 , PostForReturnDto , ResolutionContext )
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object , ResolutionContext )
   at AutoMapper.Mapper.Map[TDestination](Object source) in C:\projects\automapper\src\AutoMapper\Mapper.cs:line 35

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mapping collections using AutoMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623993/mapping-collections-using-automapper)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that you are mapping the `List<Post>` not the `Post` instance like it should be

try like below

```cs
var posts = await _repo.GetPosts();

var res = posts.Select(_ => _mapper.Map<PostToReturn>(_));

return Ok(res);
```

or you can map the collection having generic argument as [documentation says](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Lists-and-arrays.html)

```
IEnumerable<PostToReturn> postToReturn= mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Post>, IEnumerable<PostToReturn>>(posts);
```

UPD Seems your `GetPosts()` implementation lacks some `Where` or `Take` filter. It takes all posts right now and it can cause performance problem in the production if there are a lot of posts.

Comment: Yes, I have a separate method that takes all posts of all users for now, but later on, I will add some filters.